# Error when installing WxPython in linux mint

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, wxwidgets, linux-mint

I try to install WxPython in Linux Mint, and install all the packages that you ask for before installing WxPython, and when you finish downloading it, it gives running so:

`setup.py install for wxPython ...`

and does nothing else.

And install these packages:

```
 Dpkg-dev
 Build-essential
 Python2.7-dev # use appropriate Python version here
 Libjpeg-dev
 Libtiff-dev
 Libsdl1.2-dev
 Libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
 Libnotify-dev
 Freeglut3
 Freeglut3-dev
 Libsm-dev
 Libgtk2.0-dev
 Libwebkitgtk-dev
```

Comment: You can use `pip install wxPython` nowadays. However it may fail if you don't have some the prerequisites installed, such as webkit.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Mint Menu button
Select "Package Manager"
You are now running `Synaptic`
Type in the name of each package that you require and if it is not already installed, select it for installation. (Beside each package name is a box, Green if already installed, White if not)
Once you have selected all of the packages that you require, Click the `Apply` button.
Synaptic will do the rest of the work for you, including loading additional package dependencies.

Comment: Note that this will likely install an old (or really old) version of wxPython

Comment: @MikeDriscoll As of Mint 18.2 it will install wxpython 3.0.2.0 gtk2 (classic). Note that the question refers to python2.7(and Lord help us gstreamer0.10), so I assume that all will be well with an "older" version of wx even if it is 2.8, it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

See https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/

The existing wheels for Ubuntu-16.04 should work for Mint 17, and probably 18. Otherwise the rest of the page will help you install the necessary prerequisites that will allow pip to build wxPython wheels for you.